# Handling jmeter concurrent users with if statements. Good or Bad? Why?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, stress-testing

What is the best practice for handling users workflow and action path?

I was wondering how I should handle my concurrent users in Jmeter and what would be the best way. The main question is, if the example shown below considered to be good for performance testing? If not, what would be a better way?

My test:

```
CSV data config (list of users and passwords)
Thread group (30 users)
    Once Only Controller
        Login
    IF Controller (action 1) - Checks if username from CSV file matches
        LOOP Controller
            load page
            do action
            finish action
    IF Controller (action 2) - Checks if username from CSV file matches
        LOOP Controller
            load page
            do action
            finish action
```

Pretty much if controllers check if username matches, do the action else keep going until the next match. The reason for that is to isolate specific users ONLY to do a specific action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many different experiences and test cases, I realized for functional/regression testing it's ok to use IF statements, but for load testing, it is better if you use single login with many privileges of those users.

This is the way I ended up finishing that test case